# WSO2 EMM Command Issue to phone slow to receive

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have setup a WSO2 EMM in a test enviroment and enrolled an Android Phone for testing. In the testing, I notice that all the command that issued from my WSO2 EMM to the enrolled Android phone seems to be very slow in receving it. E.g Ring the phone, send notification to phone, mute phone etc, all of them take more than 10 mins to perform each.

Both the server and phone are connected to the same network. Is there anywhere I should be looking to improve this ?

Comment: If you have selected GCM as the option its highly depend on the GCM server as Hasunie mentioned below. That cannot be controlled from our end. For local notification approach you can define a lower value. But remember more calls can drain your battery etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are two notification methods for Android OS.
GCM(The Google Cloud Messaging) and Local

If you select **Local** notification method from the Android Platform configuration/notifier Type,provide the Notifier Frequency (in milliseconds) - Defines the time interval for the Andorid Agent to automatically trigger the wake-up command.
[sign to EMM console>>Platform configuration>> Android Configuration>>Notifier Type]

If the notification type is GCM, when there are pending operations that need to be enforced on a device, WSO2 EMM server will send a push notification to the GCM server and the GCM server will in-turn send the message to the respective Android Agent that is within the Android device. When the Android Agent receives the push notification, it will communicate with WSO2 EMM server and receive the list of pending operations that need to be enforced on the Android device.